# Why is it safer to force type conversion to a temporary object of a class than to wait for the argument to be automatically converted implicitly

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a simple multi-threaded program as follows：

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void myprint(const string& s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}
int main()
{
    char buf[] = "hello world!";
    thread obj(myprint, buf);
    obj.detach();
    cout << "end!!!" << endl;
}
```

This approach proved to be unsafe, as the main thread could end before the string was implicitly converted

A successful solution is to construct the string as a temporary string object when the passing of parameters, e.g `thread obj(myprint, string(buf));`
Perhaps it is because I have doubts about when threads begin to exist and I cannot understand why this solution is successful.Why artificially constructed temporary objects do not die out with the end of the main thread

Comment: I'm amused that this question is marked as a duplicate three times, and the three questions it is marked as a duplicate of are all quite different from each other :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Hmm. It's a bit of an 'edge-case' when a question is closed as a "compound duplicate", like here. I came across this in the Reopen Votes review queue but, as a reopen vote from me would be unilateral, I'm choosing to skip.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `main()` is returning before your thread has had a chance to fully execute.  That means that the `int m` local variable declared inside `main()` gets destroyed, and then any subsequent reads of that variable (via the `m_i` reference in your TA object) by the thread invoke undefined behavior -- most likely that memory location got overwritten by some other data which (often) happens to be zero.

The fix is to replace `myobj.detach()` in your `main()` function with `myobj.join()`, so that `main()` will not return until after the child thread has exited, and therefore the `m` variable will remain valid across the child thread's entire lifetime.